# paper-scroll-header-panel not working

Tags: polymer, web-component, paper-elements

HTML document body contains two independent `paper-scroll-header-panel`s inside a `neon-animated-page`. After switching the `neon-animated-page` from page 0 to page 1, the `paper-scroll-panel` on page 1 is not working.

http://jsbin.com/winedi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason : paper-scroll-header-panel when it is first loaded calculates the header height. Then it listens to only iron-resize event. But neon animated pages do not fire iron-resize event while switching pages.
From https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-scroll-header-panel/blob/master/paper-scroll-header-panel.html. line number 230

```
 * By default, the height will be measured when it is ready.  If the height
       * changes later the user needs to either set this value to reflect the
       * new height or invoke `measureHeaderHeight()`.
```

Solution : I've solved this issue by calling measureHeaderHeight() method of the second paper-scroll-header-panel explicitly. check this http://jsbin.com/visazasena/edit?html,output

```
Polymer({
  is: "inbox-view",

  next_page: function() {
    document.querySelector("#main-page").selected = 1;
  }

});
```

Change this to

```
Polymer({
  is: "inbox-view",

  next_page: function() {
    document.querySelector("#main-page").selected = 1;
    document.querySelector("#panel").measureHeaderHeight();

  }
});
```

Comment: document.querySelector("patent-view paper-scroll-header-panel").fire("iron-resize");